# Should a downvote count against a user who edited your post if they changed its meaning?

Tags: discussion

So I had a question a while back on programmers, but I feel the idea applies equally to stackoverflow.  Basically my question was edited in a way that changed its meaning in a significant way - not a grammatical edit.

For example, my question was asking about which is considered best practice in the industry among a list of options. It was changed to mean when is it appropriate to use each one.

If it was downvoted after that point should the down vote count against the editor and not myself?

Comment: Generally, simply rollback the edit. But "my question was asking about which is considered best practice in the industry among a list of options" - in that case, both you and the editor are at fault here. That question should be closed as "primarily opinion based" (or potentially "too broad"), not edited or answered. SO questions should be about a _specific_ programming problem; asking which of a list of options is "best practice" does not fit the SO model. Ask a specific question and trust that the community will upvote the best answer ("worst practice" answers usually don't get any upvotes).

Comment: @l4mpi, if you read my question you would see my question was NOT about SO, It was about Programmers. Advice specific to SO is not relevant here.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you should have asked on the programmers.SE meta, this advice is of course still relevant. Simply presenting a list of options and asking which of these is "best practice" [is a bad question regardless of where it is asked](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/8221) and should be closed on programmers.se as well. The main difference is that such a question would be generally unacceptable on SO, while on programmers the edit you describe actually made it somewhat on-topic (although it might have still been too broad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As l4mpi suggested in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287183/should-a-downvote-count-against-a-user-who-edited-your-post-if-they-changed-its#comment160903_287183), if someone edits your question to the point of changing the meaning substantially, roll it back (if this is not the first such edit to the post, flag for moderator attention to avoid an edit war). You may also want to edit your question to clarify because it is likely the person who edited misunderstood something in your question if they edited to the point of changing the meaning of the question.

> If it was downvoted after that point should the down vote count against the editor and not myself?

How who is responsible for upcoming votes going to be determined? You cannot just have a rule that if votes come after an edit, then the editor is the one who should have their reputation adjusted by the votes. For one thing, what if multiple editors edit the question? Who is responsible for what? But even in simpler cases, it is not rare for someone to fix an egregious problem in a question *without* changing the meaning of the question.